# Updating cells using dataset read from xls file and save to CSV file

Tags: c#, excel, dataset, oledb

can somebody tell me why this update procedure doesn't work? I want to read data to dataset from XLS and it works just fine but UPDATE doesn't work at all. No errors, no changes, like it doesn't exist. The file creates but values are just a copy from original xls.

Xls sheet format is pretty simple, one column: id 1 2 3

```
       string string_conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=path\name.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(string_conn);
        conn.Open();

        DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        string[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            i++;
        }

        comboBox1.DataSource = excelSheets;
        string xlsSheet = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + xlsSheet + "]", conn);
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataset);

        adapter.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand ("UPDATE " + xlsSheet + " SET id = " + tbox1.Text + " WHERE id = " + tbox2.Text + "", conn);
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Char, 255).SourceColumn = "id";
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Oldid", OleDbType.Char, 255, "id").SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

        adapter.Update(dataset);
        dataset.AcceptChanges();


        DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
        dtable = dataset.Tables[0];


        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var field in dr.ItemArray)
            {
                str.Append(field.ToString());
                str.Append(", ");
            }
            str.Replace(",", str.AppendLine().ToString(), str.Length - 1, 1);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(str.ToString()); //for test's sake

        string pathFile = @"path\filename.csv";

        if (!File.Exists(pathFile))
        {
            File.Create(pathFile).Close();
        }

        File.AppendAllText(pathFile, str.ToString());
```

Something is wrong with parameters probably but I tried this way and also no go (I added 2nd column so id stays the same just to find proper row), I get UPDATE command syntax error on execute:

```
string string_conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=path\arkusz.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";

        OleDbConnection conn= new OleDbConnection(string_conn);
        conn.Open();

        DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        string[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            i++;
        }

        comboBox1.DataSource = excelSheets;
        string xlsSheet = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + xlsSheet + "]", conn);
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataset);

        adapter.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE " + xlsSheet + " SET nazwa = @nazwa WHERE id = @id", conn);

   adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", tbox1.Text).OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nazwa", tbox2.Text).OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
        adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        adapter.Update(dataset);
        dataset.AcceptChanges();


        DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
        dtable = dataset.Tables[0];



        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var field in dr.ItemArray)
            {
                str.Append(field.ToString());
                str.Append(", ");
            }
            str.Replace(",", str.AppendLine().ToString(), str.Length - 1, 1);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());

        string sciezkaPlik = @"path\filename.csv";

        if (!File.Exists(sciezkaPlik))
        {
            File.Create(sciezkaPlik).Close();
        }

        File.AppendAllText(sciezkaPlik, str.ToString());
```

I solved the issue. For future reference it works well like this:

```
 string string_conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=path\arkusz.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(string_conn);
        conn.Open();

        DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        string[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];

        int i = 0;

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
        {
            excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            i++;
        }

        comboBox1.DataSource = excelSheets; 
        string xlsSheet = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + xlsSheet + "]", conn);

        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataset);


        OleDbCommand odbc = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE ["+xlsSheet+"] SET nazwa = " + txtNewValue.Text + " WHERE id = " + txtID.Text + "", conn);

        adapter.UpdateCommand = odbc;

        odbc.Parameters.AddWithValue("nazwa", txtNewValue.Text).OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
        odbc.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", txtID.Text).OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;

        odbc.ExecuteNonQuery();

        dataset.Clear();
        adapter.Fill(dataset);

        DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
        dtable = dataset.Tables[0];

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtable.Rows) 
        {
            foreach (var field in dr.ItemArray) /
            {
                str.Append(field.ToString());
                str.Append(", ");
            }
            str = str.Replace(',', '\n'); 
        }

        string filePath= @"path\filename.csv"; 

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Create(filePath).Close();
        }

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, str.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - I think it may be that this line needs to have the parameters put in as a question mark instead of having the actual values passed in, so more like this:

```
adapter.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand ("UPDATE " + xlsSheet + " SET id = ? WHERE id = ?", conn);
```

Then your next couple of lines are correct, they are clever enough to replace the question marks from the UpdateCommand with the actual values at run time:

```
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Char, 255).SourceColumn = "id";
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Oldid", OleDbType.Char, 255, "id").SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
```

Comment: I changed it for testing to: ("UPDATE Arkusz1$ SET nazwa = 123 WHERE id = 1", conn); and I still get update syntax error. Arkusz1$ is a name of a worksheet in xls.

Comment: Could you paste in the syntax error please. I wonder if it is the $ sign in the name of the worksheet, try it without, but if you must keep it I think the syntax would be to put square brackets around it, so [Arkusz1$] but I have not tried it.

Comment: I solved that part. It only works if name is within brackets: [Arkusz1$], now it works :) I also somewhat worked out update parameters problem. I updated my post if you wanna take a look. Now it changes XLS table and send to CSV properly. Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Hi Mike, would you mind voting and marking this as the answer if it helped you, I need some points. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hare is a very simple method to do an insert into an Excel sheet.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection ;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
                string sql = null;
                MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
                MyConnection.Open();
                myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
                sql = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (id,name) values('5','e')";
                myCommand.CommandText = sql;
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MyConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
            }
        }
   }
}
```